# Role does not exist error when logging into Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment

My Rails app can't connect to Postgresql. I suspect it's because Postgres expects the user logging into it to be the same user logged into Ubuntu (12.10).

```
deployer@xxx:~$ whoami
deployer
deployer@xxx:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "deployer" does not exist
```

My setup followed this sequence:

a) As root@server I created a new group `admin` and a new user `deployer`

```
groupadd admin
adduser deployer --ingroup admin
ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

b) I logged in as deployer and installed Postgres

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

c) On my remote server, I logged into psql and created a new user to match my Rails app:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
create user 'my_app' with password 'secret';
create database my_app_production owner my_app;
```

For deployment, I'm using the `deployer` user. This error keeps coming up during deployment:

`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_app"`

Here's my database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_app_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: my_app
  password: secret
```

Running `\du` in psql produces this:

```
 Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 my_app     |                                                | {}
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the my_app user/role? Does this user have appropriate access to the my_app_production database?

Comment: It's attributes appear as blank. I update the question and added a table at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> deployer@xxx:~$ psql
> psql: FATAL:  role "deployer" does not exist
> ```

You need to create the user in postgres:

```
create user deployer;
```

Alternatively, add an export in your profile, e.g.:

```
export PGUSER=postgres
```

Or change calls to psql as needed: `psql -Uusername database`

Comment: Thanks, Denis, but I'm trying to connect as `my_app` not deployer. I don't need a deployer user with Postgres. Although the export command is helpful.